# Assembly - jmp condition using label

Tags: assembly, x86

In the next code:

```
    Gloat: mov eax, 0
          jmp [(ebx*4)+Tab]
    Tab:  dd F4
          dd F3
          dd F2
          dd F1
    F1: add eax, 4
    F2: add eax, 4
    F3: add eax, 4
    F4: ret
```

I don't understand What the mean of `[(ebx*4)+Tab]`. For example, If `ebx` contain `2`, What I will get on the `jmp` condition? `jmp [8+Tab]`, but what is the `Tab`?

Thanks.

Comment: This is called a "branch table" or a "jump table".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tab` is a table holding the addresses of the jump targets (`F1`, `F2` etc.), `ebx * 4` selects an entry from that table (by adding to the address of `Tab`, then dereferencing that address), which is then jumped to.

So in your example, if `EBX` is 2, we get `JMP [Tab + 8]` which becomes `JMP F2`, because the address of `F2` is 8 bytes from the start of `Tab`.